# Parsing an xml file and storing it into a database

Tags: python, mysql, xml, r

Is there a generic/automatic way in R or in python to parse xml files with its nodes and attributes, automatically generate mysql tables for storing that information and then populate those tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding

> Is there a generic/automatic way in R
>   to parse xml files with its nodes and
>   attributes, automatically generate
>   mysql tables for storing that
>   information and then populate those
>   tables.

the answer is a good old *yes you can*, at least in [R](http://www.r-project.org).

The [XML](http://cran.r-project.org/package=XML) package for R can read XML documents and return R `data.frame` types *in a single call* using the `xmlToDataFrame()` function.

And the [RMySQL](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RMySQL) package can transfer `data.frame` objects to the database *in a single command*---including table creation if need be---using the `dbWriteTable()` function defined in the common [DBI](http://cran.r-project.org/package=DBI) backend for R and provided for MySQL by [RMySQL](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RMySQL).

So in short: two lines can do it, so you can easily write yourself a new helper function that does it along with a commensurate amount of error checking.

Answer (score 4):

They're three separate operations: parsing, table creation, and data population.  You can do all three with python, but there's nothing "automatic" about it.  I don't think it's so easy.

For example, XML is hierarchical and SQL is relational, set-based.  I don't think it's always so easy to get a good relational schema for every single XML stream you can encounter.

Answer (score 1):

There's the XML package for reading XML into R, and the RMySQL package for writing data from R into MySQL.

Between the two there's a lot of work. XML surpasses the scope of a RDBMS like MySQL so something that could handle any XML thrown at it would be either ridiculously complex or trivially useless.

Answer (score 0):

We do something like this at work sometimes but not in python. In that case, each usage requires a custom program to be written. We only have a SAX parser available. Using an XML decoder to get a dictionary/hash in a single step would help a lot.

At the very least you'd have to tell it which tags map to which to tables and fields, no pre-existing lib can know that...