# xml to table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have  a table and there is a column having different XML. We have to select an xml depending on the particular id passed and display that xml in the form of a table. XML will be always different

Comment: Information on what database engine you're using would help. Some of them (such as Microsoft SQL Server) have functionality allowing you to query the content of XML.

Comment: I agree with Will Hughes. Without knowing which DBMS is used, it is nearly impossible to answer your question. Every DBMS has a different level of XML support

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reply when I posted a similar question that worked for me:
from: [Parsing an xml file and storing it into a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213696/parsing-an-xml-file-and-storing-it-into-a-database)
Is there a generic/automatic way in R to parse xml files with its nodes and attributes, automatically generate mysql tables for storing that information and then populate those tables.

The answer is a good old yes you can, at least in R.

The XML package for R can read XML documents and return R `data.frame` types in a single call using the `xmlToDataFrame()` function.

And the `RMySQL` package can transfer `data.frame` objects to the database in a single command---including table creation if need be---using the `dbWriteTable()` function defined in the common DBI backend for R and provided for MySQL by `RMySQL`.

So in short: two lines can do it, so you can easily write yourself a new helper function that does it along with a commensurate amount of error checking.